# Why would psychotic symptoms return 8 months after stopping seroquel instead of immediately?

Tags: psychosis

I have a friend who experienced a cannabis induced psychosis about 5 years ago. He was on seroquel for about 4 years. However, since seroquel caused intense side effects, he decided to stop it cold turkey 8 months ago. At first he had very bad symptoms, which got weaker and weaker for 4 months. However, after 8 months abstinence, his psychotic symptoms returned in full force.

Why would the return of the psychotic symptoms take 8 months to return after abstinence from the drug? What does that tell us?

Comment: What you saw is actually pretty typical. There aren't many studies on this, but one that [was conducted](https://ajp.psychiatryonline.org/doi/pdf/10.1176/appi.ajp.158.11.1835) found that "Mean time to exacerbation or relapse [after discontinuing anti-psychotics] was 235 days", Why it works like this isn't well understood as far as I know.